# Attribute system similar to HTTP Headers for local files

Tags: python, file-io, go, attributes, metadata

I am in the process of writing a program and need some guidance. Essentially, I am trying to determine if a file has some marker or flag attached to it. Sort of like the attributes for a HTTP Header.

If such a marker exists, that file will be manipulated in some way (moved to another directory).

My question is:

Where exactly should I be storing this flag/marker? Do files have a system similar to HTTP Headers? I don't want to access or manipulate the contents of the file, just some kind of property of the file that can be edited without corrupting the actual file--and it must be rather universal among file types as my potential domain of file types is unbound. I have some experience with Web APIs so I am familiar with HTTP Headers and json. Does any similar system exist for local files in windows? I am especially interested in anyone who has professional/industry knowledge of common techniques that programmers use when trying to store 'meta data' in files in order to access them later. Or if anyone knows of where to point me, as I am unsure to what I should be researching.

For the record, I am going to write a program for Windows probably using Golang or Python. And the files I am going to manipulate will be potentially all common ones (.docx, .txt, .pdf, etc.)

Comment: If you're looking to detect a wide range of content types, what you really need is something like: https://tika.apache.org/. Otherwise, Go HTTP pkg has a basic `DetectContentType` that can pick up on some MIME types. Most of the time you'll have to rely on the file headers or the extension for type detection (there are packages for this).

Comment: @MrSaints I am looking for a non-Web based solution. Its a program designed for moving around files on windows based on whether or not they have a 'file attribute'. I was just likening what I need to HTTP Headers. Additionally, I do not need to determine the content type, I was hoping for a method that allowed me to edit the 'headers' of all files, regardless of their content type. Thanks.

Comment: File metadata, such as the title of a PDF, the number of lines in an Office XML Document (.docx), the artist in an MP3 file, etc., are all file-specific. NTFS provides an API for this sort of information using its ["Alternate Data Streams"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/416cf926-a091-4028-8d09-f9d93c3b1ba7/read-any-file-details-and-metadata-using-c?forum=vclanguage#bf763052-f2c4-4578-ba33-2a2105ac5447) capability, assuming Windows has created the ADS for the file in the first place. I'm not aware of any Go packages to support getting this information though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metadata you wish to add is best kept in a separate file or database for all files.

Or in another file with same name and different extension or prefix, that you can make hidden.

Relying on a file system is very tricky and your data will be bound by the restrictions and capabilities of the file system your file is stored on.
And, you cannot count on your data remaining intact as any application may wish to change these flags.

And some of those have very specific, clearly defined use, such as creation time, modification time, access time...

See, if you need only flagging the document, you may wish to use creation time, which will stay unchanged through out the live of this document (until is copied) to store your flags. :D

Very dirty business, unprofessional, unreliable and all that.

But it's a solution. Poor one, but exists.

I do not know that FAT32 or NTFS file systems support any extra bits for flagging except those already used by the OS.
Unixes EXT family FS's do support some extra bits. And even than you should be careful in case some other important application makes use of them for something.

Mac OS may support some metadata by itself, but I am not 100% sure.

On Windows, you have one more option to associate more data with a file, but I wouldn't use that as well.

Well, NTFS file system (FAT doesn't support that) has a feature called streams.

```
In essential, same file can have multiple data streams under itself. I.e. You have more than one file contents under same file node.
```

To be more clear. Same file contains two different files.

When you open the file normally only main stream is visible to the application. Applications must check whether the other streams are present and choose the one they want to follow.

So, you may choose to store metadata under the second stream of the file.

But, what if all streams are taken?

Even more, anti-virus programs may prevent you access to the metadata out of paranoya, or at least ask for a permission.
I don't know why MS included that option, probably for file duplication or something, but bad hackers made use of the fact that you can store some data, under existing regular file, that nobody is aware of.

Imagine a virus writing it's copy into another stream of one of programs already there.

All that is needed for it to start, instead of your old program next time you run it is a batch script added to task scheduler that flips two streams making the virus data the main one.

Nasty trick! So when this feature started to be abused, anti-virus software started restricting files with multiple streams, so it's like this feature doesn't exist.

If you want to add some metadata using OS's technology, use Windows registry,
but even that is unwise.

What to tell you?
Don't add metadata to files, organize a separate file, or index your data in special files with same name as the file you are refering to and in same folder.

Comment: I appreciated your full range of possibilities! Thereby: answer. Although thank you @saq7 as well. It looks like both you and Dalen came to the same conclusion of using a database. So I guess I will look into that. Thanks all!

Comment: I'd add that `extN` file systems (and also `XFS`, `ZFS`, `JFS` etc) support the so-called "POSIX extended attributes" and "user's extended attributes". Some filesystems require specific mount-time flags to enable them others default to enabling them. The keywords to google: `xattr`, `setxattr`, `getxattr`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with binary files like docx and pdf, you're best off storing the metadata in seperate files or in a sqlite file.

Metadata is usually stored seperate from files, in data structures called inodes (at least in Unix systems, Windows probably has something similar). But you probably don't want to get that deep into the rabbit hole.

If your goal is to query the system based on metadata, then it would be easier and more efficient to use something SQLite. Having the meta data in the file would mean that you would need to open the file, read it into memory from disk, and then check the meta data - i.e slower queries.

If you don't need to query based on metadata, then storing metadata in the file might make sense. It would reduce the dependencies in your application, but in order to access the contents of the file through Word or Adobe Reader, you'd need to strip the metadata before handing it off to the application. Not worth the hassle, usually

Comment: Might get lucky with some formats - docx is a zip file, perhaps adding data inside the archive wouldn't confuse MS Word. At least it shouldn't. But as for other formats, well, +1 for mentioning sqlite